# Interpolation on bond issuance data

Tags: regression, panel-data, finance, interpolation, aggregation

I am currently working on an analysis on bond issuance during the COVID pandemic.

I will run a linear regression of spread on multiple bond issuance characteristics but also on multiple firm key-characteristics (such as profitability, tangibility, market to book ratio, etc.).

My problem is that I only have these firm characteristics on a quarterly-basis, while I have the information on bond issuance on a daily basis.

I thought about aggregating all issuances of a firm in a quarter but since the issue characteristics also depend on the issue and may not me numeric (such as the issue type), this will lead to an erroneous analysis. Aggregating might also lead to statistical misconceptions since the financial quarter end of each company is not necessarily the same.

The only solution I came up with is giving a monthly stamp to each issue, identifying the company that issued them by a company identifier and group "same-company-belonging" issues by a unique bond identifier. But for that, I would also need to change the data on the firms' key-characteristics.

I was thinking about doing an interpolation to get the monthly data from the quarters, but I am unsure if this is a good idea or if it is going to lead me to false conclusions.

Do you guys think an interpolation would work? If yes, which do you recommend me to do? If not, do you have any other ideas?